# IE8-9 hiding pictures?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

[image: Chrome shows pictures]

Chrome shows pictures

[image: Chrome shows font]

Chrome shows font

[image: IE(8-9) hides pictures]

IE(8-9) hides pictures

[image: IE(8-9) hides font]

IE(8-9) hides font

### Tested:

Opera 11.10 (Blocks some links and adds random margins)

Firefox 26.0 (OK)

IE 8 (Hides images/font/background)

IE 9 (Hides images/font)

IE 11 (OK)

Chrome 31.0.1650.63 m (OK)

### HTML:

```
<button type="button" id="hideshow" value="Hide" class="css3button">
Hide 
</button>

<div id="kuvia">
                        <table style="position: relative; top: 0px;">
                        <tr cellspacing="200">
                           <td><span id="kuviavarjo"><a href="http://businessforum98.fi/"><img alt="Business Forum logo" src="css/images/businessforum.gif"></a></span></td>
                           <td><span id="kuviavarjo"><a href="http://www.laurea.fi/"><img alt="Laurea logo" src="css/images/laurea.gif"></a></span></td>
                           <td><span id="kuviavarjo"><a href="http://w3.fi/"><img alt="W3 Group logo" src="css/images/w3.gif"></a></span></td>
                           </tr>
                        </table>
```

### CSS:

```
   button.css3button {
        margin-top: 0px;
        right: 0%;
        font-family: Century Gothic;
        font-size: 14px;
        width: 5%;
        height: 36px;
        top: 0px;
        position: relative;
        color: #ffffff;
        background: black;
        background: black;
        -moz-border-radius: 0px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
        border-radius: 0px;
        border: 0px solid #000000;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
        position: fixed;
        opacity: 0.6;
    }

    button.css3button:focus {
    outline: none;
    }

   table#kuvia{
background:red; 
height: 100px; 
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
text-align: center;
display: inline;
list-style: none;
}

td:hover > #kuviavarjo {
border: 1px dashed lightgreen;
}

#kuviavarjo {
height: 75px;
width: 100px;
display: inline-table;
}

#kuvia img {
height: 75px;
width: 100px;
display: inline-table;
}

#kuvia img:hover {

}
```

Comment: show your proper html and css of those "hidden" images: are they floating? what position? etc.

Comment: oh sorry, forgot that.

Comment: a jsfiddle.net woule be good

Comment: I suspect this is a path problem. Is `css/images` a subdirectory of that page's directory?

Comment: It is. I've tried with '\'s too, but it won't change anything.

Comment: Are there any errors in the Console, like "source not found"?

Comment: For the fonts check Font Squirrel to convert your fonts in to all the different formats that are needed to support the different browsers. http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Comment: @andyb Can't check it anymore. My trial at BrowserStack just ran out... There were some, but I couldn't check them.

Comment: _Definitely_ mention it is on BrowserStack next time. I would try a real browser if possible.

Comment: I tried IE11 in IE9 mode. It works pretty fine now as I followed the instructions below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First problem -> `ID` should be used only one time on a page. 
Look at your `spans` - 3 elements have the same `ID`. Change that use a `class`. 
Another problem: You don't have table with the `ID`: **`table#kuvia`**. 
Correct would be: **`#kuvia table`**.

Use `img{display: block;}`. **
`list-style` property is for `lists`, don't use it with `tables`.